# production of a matrix and a tensor

Tags: python, numpy

now I have below two objects:

```
A = np.array(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), dtype=object)
x = np.array(range(1,9)).reshape(2,2,2).transpose(0,2,1)
```

With this setting, I want to have a 3D matrix as follows:

```
array([[['abb' 'aaabbbb'],
        ['cdd' 'cccdddd']],

       [['aaaaabbbbbb' 'aaaaaaabbbbbbbb'],
        ['cccccdddddd' 'cccccccdddddddd']]]
```

I have tried `np.tensordot(A, x, 1)` with some options, but I didn't have a desired result. Hope someone helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
A.reshape(2, 2)@x
```

It gives:

```
array([[['abb', 'aaabbbb'],
        ['cdd', 'cccdddd']],

       [['aaaaabbbbbb', 'aaaaaaabbbbbbbb'],
        ['cccccdddddd', 'cccccccdddddddd']]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: you should have shown that this worked.  Look at the OPs followup question